# Help with a matrix problem

Tags: matrices, problem-solving

I'm stuck with the following matrix problem:

Consider $A = $$\{ X \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{C})\ \mid X =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 \\
0 & b \end{array} \right); a, b \in \mathbb{C}; a, b \neq {0}\}$

Find all sets $H \subset A$ such that $card(H) = 7$ and $X, Y \in H \Leftrightarrow X * Y \in H$

Comment: What have you done so far? Does $card(H)$ denote the number of elements of $H$?

Comment: Yes it does. So far I've tried finding such set $H$ trying to put only $\pm1$ and $\pm i$ as values for $a$ and $b$ . But didn't succeed to find anything useful..

Comment: So you really mean $\iff$ or $\implies$?

Comment: If $X, Y \in H$ then $X * Y \in H$